# Load MP3 from Server for AudioClip

Tags: java, audio, javafx

I want to load a MP3 File from a server to use it as AudioClip in my JavaFX 8 Application. 
When I try to run the application I get the following Exception:

> Caused by: MediaException: MEDIA_INACCESSIBLE : could not connect to media (http://domain.tld/download/private/03_test-song.mp3)

Here is the code where I create the AudioClip:

```
AudioClip songAudio = new AudioClip("http://domain.tld/download/private/03_test-song.mp3");
```

I can access the mp3 file via my browser and it works correctly.
Where is my problem?

Comment: Well, if I click on the link, it says server not found...

Comment: @fabian Yeah that's because I have replaced the url with some dummy data. Here is the correct link that works and I use in my Application: http://hack4life.org/download/privat/03_big-leagues.mp3